# carrierwave image not loading into source code

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, carrierwave

Not sure what I'm doing wrong on this one. I've followed the Rails Cast for Carrierwave but am having a strange bug where the image isn't showing at all - the (HTML) source code is showing the image tag but nothing inside it.

Portfolio Model code:

```
 class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :content, presence: true
  mount_uploader :feature_image, FeatureImageUploader   
end
```

Feature Image Uploader code:

```
class FeatureImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
 storage :file

 def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
 end

 def extension_white_list
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
 end
end
```

Show.html.haml code:

```
= @portfolio.title
=image_tag @portfolio.feature_image_url.to_s
=markdown(@portfolio.content).html_safe
```

And my form code:

```
.field
 = f.label :title
 %br
 = f.text_field :title

.field
 = f.label :date
 %br
 = f.datetime_select :date

.field
 = f.label :content
 %br
 = f.text_area :content, rows: 10

.field
 = f.label :feature_image
 = f.file_field :feature_image

.actions
 = f.submit
```

And my HTML source code is showing:

```
<img src=""/>
```

I've run my rake tests and everything is fine, no failures. Would someone mind having a look for me, would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

This is my pastebin from the Server logs when I add a new portfolio entry - http://pastebin.com/1zNxB975

Comment: from docs I see your code should look like: `=image_tag @portfolio.feature_image.url` , also can you confirm if your image is uploaded? could be that attributes are saved into db but no file actually is saved.

Comment: one more thing here - having empty `url` to `src attribute` might be because `attributes` of the `image` are not saved, in this case you'll need to post `logs` of the server when you upload an image.

Comment: Hey I adjusted the image_tag but no dice. I've edited my original post to include the Server Logs, I can't tell if it's being saved or not. @magnum2002

Comment: so you got an error in logs `Unpermitted parameters: feature_image`, need to see `portofolios_controller`

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add `feature_image` to your permitted parameters?

Comment: I did indeed, thanks @jcm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in views**

```
=image_tag @portfolio.feature_image.url
```

and controller

**portofolios_controller.rb**

```
...
private
    def portofolio_params
      params.require(:portofolio).permit(:title, :date, :content, :feature_image)
    end
```

not sure about the other params you might have and need, but `:feature_image` is a must.