# add new column to table push to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Following on from my previous post ([carrierwave image not loading into source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110497/carrierwave-image-not-loading-into-source-code)), I've added a new column (feature_image) to my table portfolios.

I would like to push this to my Heroku app however I already have a number of portfolio entries on the website that I don't want to lose.

Is there anyway I can push my database changes without losing the content already on there?

Thank you!

Comment: pushing it will not affect your records, only new migration will run to add new column so you'll end up having lots of portofolios with no image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pushing it will not affect your records (**unless you have some special code that resets the db each time you do a push - never heard of such cases, but who knows**), only new migration will be executed to add new column so you'll end up having lots of portofolios with no image.

rails app saves all `migrations` numbers into `schema_migration` table in `db`, so next time you'll run a `migration` it will migrate only the ones that are not in `schema_migration`.

in my case if I'll run migration only `20140109214830_add_is_new_to_messages` will be migrated as its number is not `schema_migration`, it works this way on local machine and the same when pushing.

[image]

after migrating it, migration number will be saved into `schema_migration` table (line 44):

[image]

`git push heroku master && heroku run rake db:migrate && heroku restart`

Comment: So if I have 20140114071826_add_feature_image_to_portfolios, do I do heroku run rake --trace db:migrate VERSION=0140114071826? @rmagnum2002

Comment: do you need trace? I think `heroku run rake db:migrate` should be enough and no need to specify the migration number unless you want to migrate a specific one, for example you have migrations with numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 and you want to migrate number 3, in this case you specify the migration number.. In your case you are running migration for all that are not in `schema_migration`... so `heroku run rake db:migrate` is what you need.. it will skip the existing ones, and will migrate the new ones only

Comment: also you might need to push changes to heroku first and then run migrations... something like `git push heroku master && heroku run rake db:migrate` in one line.

Comment: Yeah I did the push first, then the migrate. Hmmm, getting the 'We're sorry, but something went wrong.' Checked my local version - can add a new portfolio/edit existing portfolio to include a feature image fine, rake tests are fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: join this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45200/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-21114592-add-new-column-to-table-push-to-herok

Comment: Here's the pastebin - don't have enough rep yet to talk in chat.
http://pastebin.com/DVDyNqgb