# Add S3 with Carrierwave to Rails App for Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm trying to add S3 to my Heroku app however, I'm getting the same problem I had on a previous question ([carrierwave image not loading into source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110497/carrierwave-image-not-loading-into-source-code)) where the image url isn't loading into the source code.

Feature_image_uploader.rb has this instead of storage :file:

```
storage :fog
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'carrierwave'

gem 'fog', '~> 1.3.1'
```

fog.rb file:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
 config.fog_credentials = {
 :provider               => 'AWS',                
 :aws_access_key_id      => 'xxx',                 
 :aws_secret_access_key  => 'yyy',                      
 :region                 => 'eu-west-1',                  
 :host                   => 's3.example.com',             
 :endpoint               => 'https://s3.example.com:8080' 
  config.fog_directory  = 'luchiauploads'        
  config.fog_public     = false                     
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'} 
end
```

It has my access key ID and secret access key inserted. I also ran the terminal commands as per Heroku's instructions.

And this pastebin is my server log: http://pastebin.com/TH68bhn4

And rake tests have no errors.

I know I'm missing something really simple, but can't work out what. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error (line5 in pastebin):

```
Unpermitted parameters: feature_image_cache, remove_feature_image
```

you need to add these parameters to permited attributes:

**portofolios_controller.rb**

```
...
private
    def portofolio_params
      params.require(:portofolio).permit(:title, :date, :content, :feature_image, :feature_image_cache, :remove_feature_image)
    end
```